# Image under $w=e^{1/z}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to find the image of $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}; 0<|z|<r\}$, with $r>0$, under $w=e^{1/z}$.

I started this way: if $z=|z|e^{i\theta}\in S$, by Euler's formula
$$
    1/z
  = |z|^{-1}(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)
  = |z|^{-1}\cos\theta-|z|^{-1}i\sin\theta.
$$
Considering $w=|w|e^{i\alpha}$ as image of $z$,
$$
    |w|e^{i\alpha}
  = e^{|z|^{-1}\cos\theta} e^{-|z|^{-1}i\sin\theta}.
$$
And then
$$
           |w| = e^{|z|^{-1}\cos\theta}
  \implies \ln|w| = |z|^{-1}\cos\theta
  \implies \cos\theta = |z| \ln|w|.
$$
And also
$$
           \alpha =-|z|^{-1}i\sin\theta
  \implies \sin\theta =-\alpha |z|.
$$

What do I have to do now?

Comment: This question becomes very easy if you can guess what the image should be. In  my answer I have quoted a deep theorem to show that the image consists of all complex numbers except $0$. It is  a trivial matter, however, to verify that this is indeed the case with the help of logarithms.

Comment: @did the answer is not clear there too

Comment: That may be so, and so what?

Comment: @did sorry what do you mean?

Comment: That this is not a reason to deliberately repost the same question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

$e^{\frac 1 z}$ has an essential singularity at $0$ so the image of any deleted neighborhhod of $0$ contains all complex numbers except possibly one (by Picard's Theorem). The exceptional value is obviously $0$ so the image is $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, whatever $r$ is. If you are not familiar with these concepts you can try to verify my claim directly by solving the equation $e^{\frac 1 z} =w$ for a given $w$ in $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Second method: take $z=\frac 1 {\log w +2n\pi i}$ for a large positive integer $n$ where $\log w$ is any logarithm of $w$.

Comment: This exercise is in a list of one book, in a chapter where Picard's Theorem hasn't been mentioned yet... So please try to help me only using basic knowledge about complex functions. Thanks for your attention

Comment: @MarcosPaulo I have already done that. Just ignore all the theory and  see the second method. Take any non-zero complex number $w$. Note that $\frac 1 {\log w+2n\pi i} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty $ so $|\frac 1 {\log w+2n\pi i}| <r$ if $n$ is sufficiently large. If $z=\frac 1 {\log w+2n\pi i}$ then  $e^{1/z} =e^{\log w +2n \pi i} =e^{\log w}=w$. Hence $w$ is in the range of the function.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo For more clarity let me add that if $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r >0$ and $0 \leq \theta <2\pi $, you can take $w$ to be $\log r+i\theta $.

Comment: you said that $e^{1/z}=e^{\log w +2n\pi i}$. why can it be $e^{-(\log w +2n\pi i)}$?

Comment: For a given $w$ I am defining $z$ in a particular way to show that $w$ is in the range of the function. I don't have to find all $z$ such that $f(z)=w$. Just one $z$ will do. With my definition of $z$ there is no scope for a minus sign in the exponent.

Comment: Do you think this way it is easier than my reasoning above? I didn't understand your point yet :(

Comment: @MarcosPaulo What you have done is not wrong, but it is incomplete. You have found $|z|$ and $\theta$ but you don't necessarily have $0<|z|<r$. You have to exploit the non-uniqueness of $\theta$ to get this inequality. That is what I have done by using logarithm.

Comment: I can't organize these ideas so that I can answer this question like in a test. When you choose $w$, it seems that you got it from nowhere... How to construct it (in the same sense that you can do it with any formula)?